# What age to show my children the film, Threads

Tags: television

Back in the UK schools screened to teenage children the film Threads to teach them about the futility and horror of nuclear war. I think all today's children should have the same trauma imposed on them. What age would be the most effective while minimising the psychological scarring?

Comment: It _entirely_ depends on the maturity of your kids...

Comment: The child should see the film when the child is ready, and not before. That depends on the child and the reason you want them to see it, and of all of us, you're the only one who knows your child. There is no one definitive answer to this question.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I think that answers the question perfectly. I will take that as the answer. Yes the question is primarily opinion based, but then so is everything ultimately.

Comment: @Sentinel - One of my passions is science (most specifically medicine and molecular biology), so I must disagree with everything being primarily opinion based. No matter what your opinion of it is, gravity is a force you need to reckon with *all the time*.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I am a Popperian falsificationist. I don't agree that gravity is something that must always be reckoned with in that way. Similar to how British explorers need not have reckoned with swans being always white.

Comment: @Sentinel - Oh well, like I said, everyone has opinions. I'm watching Threads, btw. Haven't got to any gory parts yet, though.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Let me know how you got on with it. If I recall correctly it takes quite a while for things to get worrying.

Answer (score 2):

> I think all today's children should have the same trauma imposed on them.

I don't think you should be traumatizing children.

It may not be a good idea to force it on them anyway. It's good to push them out of their comfort zone, but pushing too far will lead to trauma.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Parenting.SE! Can you add an actual answer to the question ("What age ... ?")?

Comment: Absolutely. And so it should. I understand you might disagree but I think you are in the wrong and this does not answer the question. The question is what age of child is too young. Eg the UK rating is 15.

Comment: @Sentinel - Please chill. You are not *owed* an answer, and as for opinions, everybody has them. Ben is not "wrong" if you are not "wrong". There is no one answer.